# After installing SQL Server 2014 Express can't find local db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have downloaded and installed SQL Server 2014 Express
(from this site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx#Installation_Options).

The problem is that I can't connect/find my local DB server, and I can't develop DB on my local PC. How can I reach my local server?

My system consists of Windows 8.1 (no Pro or Enterprise editions) 64 bits

Checking the configuration of SQL Server with `SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager` tool, I see an empty list selecting "SQL Server Services" from the tree at the left. Below you can find a screenshot.

[image]

In the Windows Services list, there is just only one service: **"SQL Server VSS Writer"**

**EDIT**
My installation window of SQL Server 2014 is the following:
[image]

Comment: If you see no service - then you didn't really install the SQL Server **engine** - maybe you only installed the **Management Studio** GUI tools .....

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Most probably, you didn't install any SQL Server Engine service. If no SQL Server engine is installed, no service will appear in the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool. Consider that the packages `SQLManagementStudio_Architecture_Language.exe` and `SQLEXPR_Architecture_Language.exe`, available in the [Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299) contain, respectively only the Management Studio GUI Tools and the SQL Server engine.

If you want to have a full featured SQL Server installation, with the database engine and Management Studio, [download the installer file of **SQL Server with Advanced Services**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299).
Moreover, to have a sample database in order to perform some local tests, use the [Adventure Works database](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550).

Considering the package of **SQL Server with Advanced Services**, at the beginning at the installation you should see something like this (the screenshot below is about SQL Server 2008 Express, but the feature selection is very similar). The checkbox next to "Database Engine Services" must be checked. In the next steps, you will be able to configure the instance settings and other options.

Execute again the installation process and select the database engine services in the feature selection step. At the end of the installation, you should be able to see the SQL Server services in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for my long answer. My instance fetures node is empty, look at edited description above.

Comment: @JeffOrris What do you have as 'already installed'? SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server engine? My answer is about the missing installation of the SQL Server engine. You have to select, once launched the installation, the option "New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation" from the "Installation" tab. See a picture of it [here](http://it.tinypic.com/r/ele2ko/9).

Answer (score 18):

I downloaded a different installer "SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services" and found Instance Features in it. Thanks for Alberto Solano's answer, it was really helpful.

My first installer was "SQL Server 2014 Express". It installed only SQL Management Studio and tools without Instance features. After installation "SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services" my LocalDB is now alive!!!

Comment: "...with Advanced Services"--> Yes,this is the important part!

Comment: I installed the version with Tools (not Advanced) and also had the same issue. Running 'sqllocaldb create "v12.0"' at the command prompt fixed the issue - see here https://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/sql-2014-localdb-error-cannot-connect-to-locaidbv12-o/

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed that after installation of SQL server 2012 express on Windows 10 you must install ENU\x64\SqlLocalDB.MSI from official Microsoft download site. After that, you could run SqlLocalDB.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Just download and install LocalDB 64BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi can also solve this problem. You don't really need to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services.

Comment: Tried to install, but not able to find what to execute. :(

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you just installed localDB, you won't see the instance in the configuration manager. You would need to initiate it first, and then connect to it using server name (localdb)\mssqllocaldb.
[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121150/how-do-i-connect-to-localdb-from-sql-server-2014-express)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Just download and install the SQL Server suite from the following link :http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299

restart your SSMS and you should be able to "Register Local Servers" via right-click on "Local Servers Groups", select "tasks", click "register local servers"