# A downgrade path is not supported convert version 782 to 706 and earlier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mdf, downgrade, server-explorer

I am creating one application where I have used ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 4.5.2 and trying to access the SQL Server but it gives me an error that I can't access any database so I just convert it to the single user mode.

Now after converting it to Single User mode the new error comes when I am trying to access in Server Explorer, Data Connections (Default Connection), it shows me the below dialog. I am not understand what is going wrong.

I have SQL Server version 11.0.2100.60.

Please some one help me to solve this issue!

[image]

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500912/trying-to-attach-a-database-fails-because-it-is-version-782

Comment: @JamesP Both I have used but not gettting the solutions.

Comment: You need newer version of SQL server and tools,

Comment: @MarkHomer Ohhh but I have boundry not to use beyond existing softwares than how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can with that database file, you cant downgrade. You would need to create a new one with lower version and copy database structure and data into it

Comment: @MarkHomer Can I do it manually I mean I have mdf file with me so can I just do restore with the lower version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ufffff after so many solutions applied I found one from it.

Steps:

1) Change Instance name in Visual Studio [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve):

Under Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections > SQL Server Instance Name. 
   set (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

2) Change your connection string:

From:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=./SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBName.Service-20160924032113.mdf;Initial Catalog=DBName.Service-20160924032113;Integrated Security=True;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBName.Service-20160924032113.mdf;Initial Catalog=DBName.Service-20160924032113;Integrated Security=True;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

3) Remove User Instance=True from Connection String.

Thanks to James P and Mark Homer for excellent response.

Comment: Glad you found solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (using Visual Studio 2015 community)...

- In Server Explorer right-click the desired connection and select Modify Connection
- Select Advanced Options
- Change the Data Source to a different version (In my case it needed to be SQL express) press OK.

Hope it helps