# connect to sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

[image]I am trying to connect to sql server 2012 with server name ***.\SQLEXPRESS*** but I am getting error so please could anyone help me about how to get the correct server name and why SQL services are empty?

[image]

Comment: here there is an [answer][1] for your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163183/after-installing-sql-server-2014-express-cant-find-local-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163183/after-installing-sql-server-2014-express-cant-find-local-db)  and you will find a very good answer to your question.