# Is there a "test" server for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Basically, I need to work on streaming data from a SQL Server table using Node and I was wondering if there is a server somewhere that would allow for some test data to work with.

Comment: Download SQL Server Express.

Comment: Follow the accepted answer of  this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163183/after-installing-sql-server-2014-express-cant-find-local-db?rq=1

Comment: I need to have a non-local server. Something set up for the sole purpose of providing dummy data for production and testing purposes.

Comment: You can install SQL Server Express on any server you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ragic](http://www.ragic.com/) or  [Amazon.com's simpledb](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) or [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) from Google or [Dedicated DB Servers](https://appharbor.com/addons) or follow some more at [cloudboost](https://cloudboost.io/)